# best way for creating Index in mysql (multi-column/table)?

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

i have a big problem with my database..

I need a very fast query over 2 tables. 
1. table: (node)   ~42.500.000 entrys
2. table: (waynode ~51.200.000 entrys

The following query is much to slow:

```
SELECT  `node`.ID,`node`.LATITUDE,`node`.LONGITUDE,`waynode`.WAYID
    FROM  `node`, `waynode`
    WHERE  `node`.ID= `waynode`.NODEID
      AND  `node`.LATITUDE BETWEEN '49.558' AND '49.568'
      AND  `node`.LONGITUDE BETWEEN '11.3395' AND '11.3495'
    ORDER BY  `waynode`.WAYID
```

The current time is over 180 seconds..

I also have a INDEX over 2 columns created with ALTER TABLE node ADD INDEX (LATITUDE, LONGITUDE).  When i am using the following select, it's very fast:

```
SELECT  `node`.ID,`node`.LATITUDE,`node`.LONGITUDE
    FROM  `node`
    WHERE  `node`.LATITUDE BETWEEN '49.558' AND '49.568'
      AND  `node`.LONGITUDE BETWEEN '11.3395' AND '11.3495'
```

But I need the `waynode`.NODEID like in the first SQL-Statement.
May someone help me please?

best regards
Ingo

Comment: Execution plans to understand how these queries are being interpreted would go a long way to understanding where a bottleneck may lie.

Answer (score 1):

See if this runs faster:

```
SELECT  n.ID, n.LATITUDE, n.LONGITUDE,
        wn.WAYID
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  ID, LATITUDE, LONGITUDE
            FROM  `node`
            WHERE  LATITUDE  BETWEEN '49.558'  AND '49.568'
              AND  LONGITUDE BETWEEN '11.3395' AND '11.3495' 
      ) AS n
    JOIN  `waynode` AS wn  ON n.ID= wn.NODEID
    ORDER BY  wn.WAYID
```

This might also work 'fast':

```
SELECT  n.ID, n.LATITUDE, n.LONGITUDE, 
      ( SELECT  WAYID
            FROM  waynode
            WHERE  n.ID= NODEID 
      ) AS WayID
    FROM  `node` AS n
    WHERE  LATITUDE  BETWEEN  '49.558' AND '49.568'
      AND  LONGITUDE BETWEEN '11.3395' AND '11.3495'
    ORDER BY  WayID
```

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for any query you want to discuss and `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` for the tables in question.

Comment: Hello Rick James,
your first solution also takes over 180 seconds also the second.
The speedproblem is currently by asking both tables
Might there be a way of creating a specific Index for this Select?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: More discussion here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql#bounding_box